# unable to get the FB js examples working

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

This seems trivial but it's not working. Following the guide on this site: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/quickstart

This code below throws no errors to the console but seems to do nothing. nor even hitting the FB.ui function.

I'm just looking for a complete example to get started with the fb sdk in javascript and haven't seen anything.  Ultimately, all i want to do is read event info from a user's account. Not sure what I'm missing though.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
<body>

<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : 'my_id',
      xfbml      : false,
      version    : 'v2.8',
      status     : true
    });
    FB.AppEvents.logPageView();  
  };

  (function(d, s, id){
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
     js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

</script>

</body>

<script>
function test() {
        FB.ui(
        {
        method: 'share',
        href: 'https://developers.facebook.com/docs/'
        }, function(response){});   
    }
</script>

<button type="button" onclick="test()">Click Me!</button>

</html>
```

Comment: You can't call FB.ui when the page loads. You need to call it when the user clicks a button or link

Comment: @WizKid, could you provide an example code?  i continue to get the same error when following your advice.

Comment: So show us what you are doing then.

Comment: sure. i updated the code above. i get the same error when clicking the button.

Comment: If you want to read events from the users profile. Why are you using the share dialog?

Comment: reading is ultimately my goal but here im just trying to get the sample code to work but im unable to do even that.